# Can not get value from input field from a model in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a modal like

```
                <div id="addDeployment" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Deployment to {{selectedOwner==null ? 'Unassigned' : selectedOwner.Name}}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><label for="editOwnerName">Deployment Name</label></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deploymentName" id="deploymentName" [(ngModel)]="deploymentName" 
                                            placeholder="" autofocus autocomplete="off" />
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="fnAddDeploytment()">Add Deployment</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to get the value from the textBox inside function **fnAddDeploytment**
What I have done is

1. Create a variable `deploymentName : any` in the ts file.
2. Inside the **fnAddDeploytment()** function, I can not get the value of the input field by `this.deploymentName` and it outputs `undefined`

In my **.ts** file, Declared

```
 public deploymentName: any;
```

then

```
fnAddDeploytment(){
    var ownerName = this.selectedOwner.Name;
    var ownerKey = this.selectedOwner.key;
    var DeploymentName = this.deploymentName;

    console.log('Owner name is' +ownerName + ' and deployment name is ' +this.deploymentName);

  }
```

What is the problem here? I can not figure it out.

Comment: did u try `console.log(this.deploymentName)` inside `fnAddDeploytment` ?

Comment: yes, I have tried `console.log(this.deploymentName)` and it outputs  `undefined`

Comment: seems like u didn't give `name` prop to input. eg: `<input type="text" name="deploymentName" .. >`. Isn't angular throwing error in console ?

Comment: I have updated my code. This also outputs `undefined`

Comment: any console error?

Comment: no console error @ShaileshLadumor

Comment: r u successfully getting `ownerName` and `ownerKey` ?

Comment: Issue is somewhere else. produce a stackblitz/plunker

Comment: public deploymentName ='hello'; declare like and check your input. got default value into input?

Comment: Thank! Got it. ownerKey is not getting successfully. Now I can get the value. Thanks again :)